# Trunk Based Development suggestion required

Tags: version-control, branch, branching-and-merging, trunk, branching-strategy

I was looking up good resources on branching strategies after doing feature branching for quite a few years and struggling with lots of branches and merge nightmares. Feature branches did give us a good isolation in managing releases in a pretty granular way as to which features should go to release. However, the problems they posed (many branches, merge conflicts) were way more than the benefits they gave.

We work with Oracle database (with 5000 objects) at back end. We also have multiple teams working on different areas of the same product. We are using Visual Studio with TFS (no DVCS).

The more branches we create, more database instances we require to give proper  isolation in functional testing in those branches (each branch - one db instance) which are another set of problems.

We are adopting scrum and are searching for a branching model that will suit our release cycle (4 times a year) and CI builds. We are planning to do 5 regular sprint and 1 hardening sprint for each release.

From a feature branching model, we reworked our branching model to a very simple branching like below -

[image: Branching Model]

Development branch is working as our "Trunk" (for Trunk Based Development) and ALL developers (all teams) are committing to this branch (for quarterly release), testers are testing in this branch and CI server (Jenkins) is building this branch daily. We just need a clean MAIN at any time for safety as "Single Source of Truth for Last Release" which come to our use often for several reasons.

Maintenance branch is our bug fixing branch (hotfix) and is released several times during the year (irrespective of quarterly release). We prefer not to work directly on the main branch as want to have a "clean" Main branch. We do not want to let code go to Main without "manual" / functional testing done. Once a bug fix release is done, code is merged from Maintenance -> Main -> Development to integrate the bug fixes into Development.

We typically do not require the "Release Branches" as suggested in TBD since we will be continuously doing the bug fixes in the Maintenance branch, release from Maintenance and then merge the changes to Main (and then Development). We maintain only "Last release" and in case previous Release fix is required we create an old release branch from Labels in Main.

Have we modified the Trunk Based Development to an extent that it would pose problems in future? What are your suggestions?

Refer:

http://paulhammant.com/2013/12/04/what_is_your_branching_model

http://paulhammant.com/2013/04/05/what-is-trunk-based-development/#comment-2765204723

Answer (score 1):

You should make a maintence branch from the tag that was released, only if you encounter a bug. Actually that's a release branch, and it should be named for the release. Say rel_1.1. By the time you've pushed out release 1.2 and it is clear you're not going to roll back, delete rel_1.1.